# Fibonacci sequence and Pigeonhole principle

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider set $A:= \{F_{n} \mid n, \, 1 \leq n \leq 1000002\}$ where  $F_{n}$ denotes the $n$th Fibonacci number.

Prove that exist at least two numbers $F_a$ and $F_b$, such that $F_a,F_b \in A$ and $F_a$,  $F_b$ are divisible by $1000$.

I trying to use the Dirichlet's box principle, but I have problem, how to define pigeonhole.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  $F_0=1=F_1$ and clearly $1\,|\,1000$.  But, then, I think you meant something else, no?

Comment: Is it possible that you meant to require $1000\,|\,F_a$?  If so, then note that $1000=2^3\times 5^3$ so try to find indices $i,j$ for which $8\,|\,F_i$ and $125\,|\,F_j$ and then use the divisibility properties of the Fibonacci numbers.  (Note: the divisibility properties look much better if you use the convention $F_0=0,F_1=1$ instead of the convention I used earlier).

Comment: Yes. I have already corrected. Sorry.

Comment: I don't see any correction.  Anyway, assuming I guessed your intent correctly, my hint should lead to a solution pretty quickly.  Not sure it's a pencil and paper solution, but it is close.

Comment: Do you mean $1000$ divides $F_a,\ $ or $\ F_a$ divides $1000?\ \ $

Comment: $F_a$ is divisible by $1000$.

Comment: Can you use (or if not try to prove)   $n|m \implies F_n | F_m$

Answer (score 0):

Every sixth element is divisible by $8$ and every $125^{th}$ is divisible by $125$, just by computation.  Then every $750^{th}$ is divisible by $1000$

Note that we just have to find the first element divisible by any prime power.  The next number after that may not be $1$, but the recurrence is linear.  In this example, $F_7\equiv 5 \pmod 8$, but the next block is just the first block multiplied by $5$ and $0 \cdot 5=0$

Comment: "just by computation" hides a lot. Also, this does not use the pigeon hole principle.

Comment: @martycohen:  I don't think it hides anything.  I just made a spreadsheet and I justified why once you find one zero it will repeat at that period.  I agree it does not use pigeonhole.  I don't have a good pigeonhole approach.  It looks like we are supposed to use $1000^2=1000000$ but I don't see how to show there isn't a correlation that prevents a solution.

Comment: I agree that is true. Look up divisibility sequences.